# How can I reliably and consistently save PGF keys filtered by path to a macro for later use?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, key-value

I am trying to use PGF keys in TikZ with a relatively complex key tree. (Complex by my standards, that is - I'm sure it isn't that complicated in the scheme of things.)

What I hoped to do is to define a command to do following:

- set keys which are descendants of a particular path in the key tree;
- save all remaining keys to a macro;
- do a bunch of other stuff (calculations, processing, setting up);
- typeset a node using various bits of the processed information;
- tack on the macro to the node options so that, for example, generic TikZ keys get applied.

Not only can I not get this to work, I can't figure out any logic behind what works and what doesn't. At one point, my MWE wouldn't compile at all while my original document merely failed to produce the desired output.

In my actual document, none of the options I pass seem to have any effect, but I'm hoping that the MWE is getting at the same problem or, at least, one of the same problems.

Here's my current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\mymammals{}
\tikzset{
  mammals/.code={
    \tikzset{
      /pgf/key filters/is descendant of/.install key filter=/animals/mammals/,
      /pgf/key filter handlers/append filtered to/.install key filter handler=\mymammals,
      /animals/mammals/.cd,%
      #1
    }
  },
  /animals/.search also={/tikz},
  /animals/mammals/.search also={/animals,/tikz},
  /animals/mammals/.cd,
  elephant/.store in=\elephant,
  /animals/size/.style={},
}
\newcommand\mammals[1]{%
  \def\mymammals{}%
  \tikzset{mammals={#1}}%
  \node (\elephant) [circle, minimum size=5mm, draw=red, text=red] at (0,0) {x};
  \node (another \elephant) [/animals/size, \mymammals] at (\elephant) {\elephant};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mammals{
      elephant=Edward,
      text=blue,
      draw,
      minimum width=50mm,
      xshift=-10mm,
      yshift=-20mm
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I would like this to do is to produce a red circle containing a red 'x' and, 10mm to the left and 20mm below, a 50mm wide box containing the name 'Edward' in blue with the borders of the node drawn. (Not sure which colour I want here - but let's say black or red or blue would be a start!)

That is, I hope to get this:

[image: dream]

However, I get this:

[image: reality]

Now I fully accept that I don't know what I'm doing. So I am not surprised this doesn't work. That much I expect.

But why is it *partially* working? Why is Edward in blue, but the node is not drawn and the shifts are not done?

I'm aware that `/animals/size` is playing a crucial role here, but I'm not clear why. It shouldn't be switching the default path and, if it was, I should get errors. And since, in my minimised example, this is a style which does nothing at all, it seems bizarre that it should have such partial effects.

This makes me think that I should not be going about this in this way at all, but I can't figure out how I should be doing it if I don't want to put keys into families just in order to solve this problem. If I could say 'All keys which are descendants of ... go in family ...', that would be one thing, but I get the impression that the family concept is supposed to be for categories which are orthogonal to paths in the tree hierarchy.

That is, I have no idea what is going on and the manual is not helping at all. Please can I have a hint?

## EDIT

The following appears to work but I'm not sure how safe or sane it is. Nor am I entirely sure *why* it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  mammals/.code={
    \def\mysaved{}%
    \tikzset{
      /pgf/key filters/defined/.install key filter,
      /pgf/key filter handlers/append filtered to/.install key filter handler=\mysaved,
    }%
    \pgfkeysfiltered{/animals/mammals/.cd,#1}%
    \tikzset{
      /animals/mysaved/.estyle={\mysaved},
    }
  },
  /animals/.search also={/tikz},
  /animals/mammals/.search also={/animals,/tikz},
  /animals/mammals/.cd,
  elephant/.store in=\elephant,
}
\newcommand\mammals[1]{%
  \tikzset{mammals={elephant={??},#1}}%
  \node (\elephant) [circle, minimum size=5mm, draw=red, text=red] at (0,0) {x};
  \node (another \elephant) [/animals/mysaved] at (\elephant) {\elephant};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mammals{
      elephant=Edward,
      text=blue,
      draw,
      minimum width=50mm,
      xshift=-10mm,
      yshift=-20mm
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A quick test showed that \mymammals is still empty.  What were you expecting to be stored there and why?

Comment: You are obviously trying to teach yourself how to use pgfkeys.  Why don't you start simple then add complexity.  For example, when you create a new key you should always use /.initial= even if it is never used.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sure it is simple for you. However, it is incredibly obscure to me. What does the manual mean when it says that `/my key` will be 'promoted' to... ? I don't understand the idea of promotion here. Moreover, as far as I could tell, `.initial` only applies to certain kinds of keys. And it has never been obvious to me what it is meant to do. Is there any reason to use `.initial` in addition to ensuring that a key is set to some value? And why does 'Edward' get printed in blue? This is not the first time I've used PGF keys even if it looks that way. But I admit I don't get it.

Comment: I ask about `.initial` because I take it you mean I should have `elephant/.initial` but that *seems* superfluous since my real example has something like `\tikzset={mammals={elephant={??},#1}` in `\mammals` to ensure that it is always (re)set. Or else I have things like `key/.store in=\mykey` followed by `key=placeholder`. Should I have `key/.initial=something` as well? If so, why? Certainly the manual does not make this at all clear.

Comment: The other way to learn is to look at the TikZ source code and see how it uses pgfkeys.  And yes, even when I use /.default={something} I CREATE the key using /.initial={}.  There are some exceptions, like /.is family.

Comment: But why? If you are going to set it to a default anyway, why do that? What difference does it make? Not that I use `/.default`much either. If keys really are meant to be set up this way, then the manual is *extremely* misleading. And it is hardly reasonable to expect people to read the source code of the package to figure out how it should really be used. The documentation doesn't give anything like this prominence to `.initial`. Indeed, it is covered in an extremely obscure way in a section covering only a particular set of keys: not styles or code or....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30280/discussion-between-john-kormylo-and-cfr).

Comment: I'd use `/animals/mysaved/.style/.expand once=\mysaved` to be on the safe side (`\mysaved` could include fragile macros). You could also just do `\node (another \elephant) [style/.expand once=\mysaved] …;`. `.default` defines the default *value*  that is used when the key is used without a value. `.initial` defines the value of a value key (that can be overwritten be the user using `<key>=<new value>` or again `<key>/.initial=<new value>`).